# How to download images with aiohttp?

Tags: python, aiohttp

So I have a discord bot that I'm playing with to learn Python.  I have a command that downloads images, and edits/merges them, then sends the edited image to chat. I was using `requests` to do this before, but I was told by one of the library devs for discord.py that I should be using `aiohttp`instead of `requests`.  I can't find how to download images in `aiohttp`, I've tried a bunch of stuff, but none of it works.

```
if message.content.startswith("!async"):
    import aiohttp
    import random
    import time
    import shutil
    start = time.time()
    notr = 0
    imagemake = Image.new("RGBA",(2048,2160))
    imgsave = "H:\Documents\PyCharmProjects\ChatBot\Images"
    imagesend = os.path.join(imgsave,"merged.png")
    imgmergedsend =os.path.join(imgsave,"merged2.png")
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("http://schoolido.lu/api/cards/788/") as resp:
            data = await resp.json()
            cardsave = session.get(data["card_image"])
            with open((os.path.join(imgsave, "card.png")),"wb") as out_file:
                shutil.copyfileobj(cardsave, out_file)
```

is what I have right now, but that still doesn't work.

So, is there a way to download images?

Comment: You have missed `await` before `session.get(data["card_image"])`. Also `cardsave` is a response, not file-like object. You should copy bytes body from response to file manually.

Answer (score 46):

You lock loop when write file. You need use aiofiles.

```
import aiohttp        
import aiofiles

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    url = "http://host/file.img"
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        if resp.status == 200:
            f = await aiofiles.open('/some/file.img', mode='wb')
            await f.write(await resp.read())
            await f.close()
```

Comment: While methods read(), json() and text() are very convenient you should use them carefully. All these methods load the whole response in memory.

Comment: You can also use `async with` instead of opening and closing the file. E.g. ```async with aiofiles.open(path, 'wb') as f: 
 await f.write(await resp.read())```

Answer (score 10):

So I figured it out, a while ago:

```
if message.content.startswith("!async2"):
    import aiohttp
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("http://schoolido.lu/api/cards/788/") as resp:
            data = await resp.json()
            card = data["card_image"]
            async with session.get(card) as resp2:
                test = await resp2.read()
                with open("cardtest2.png", "wb") as f:
                    f.write(test)
```

I was getting a response, not an image response

Answer (score 8):

```
pdf_url = 'https://example.com/file.pdf'
    
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(pdf_url) as resp:
        if resp.status == 200:
            with open('file.pdf', 'wb') as fd:
                async for chunk in resp.content.iter_chunked(10):
                    fd.write(chunk)
```

> **While methods read(), json() and text() are very convenient you should**
> **use them carefully. All these methods load the whole response in**
> **memory.** For example if you want to download several gigabyte sized
> files, these methods will load all the data in memory. Instead you can
> use the content attribute. It is an instance of the
> aiohttp.StreamReader class. The gzip and deflate transfer-encodings
> are automatically decoded for you:

https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#streaming-response-content

Answer (score 0):

Open a get request with the server. If it responds with an HTTP 200, open a write stream and stream data as it is received.

```py
import aiohttp        
import aiofiles

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
  async with session.get(download_url) as response:
    if response.status != 200:
      raise Exception('Got non-200 response!')

    async with aiofiles.open(filepath, 'wb') as file:
      async for data, _ in response.content.iter_chunks():
        await file.write(data)
```